# Understanding Actionscript 3 Code

Tags: actionscript-3

I was given this piece of code and am trying to understand it as best as I can. I have ran the code and understand what it does, but there are a few lines which I do not know how to explain.

[Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMz4i.png)

```
var theElements = newArray["Earth", "Wind", "Fire", "Water", "Ether"];
var elements:String;
var numberOfRoles = 10;

roleThem(theElements, numberOfRoles);

function roleThem(theElements, numberOfRoles):void{

    while (numberOfRoles > 0){
        var currentElement = role(theElements);
        trace(currentElement);
        numberOfRoles--;
    }
}

function role(theArray:Array):String{

    var picker = Math.floor(Math.random()*theArray.length);
    return theArray[picker];
}
```

Here is what I have come up with so far:

In line 1 of the code shown, we have created a new Array called “theElements”. It contains 5 different elements named “Earth, Wind, Fire, Water & Ether.”

In line 2 of the code, we are creating a variable with a String function, however this line of code seems to be an error that was left in to the code as “element” does not feature within our code again. This line of code was used in a previous example and had been forgotten to be removed. We can successfully run the piece of code without any errors if we remove this line.

In line 3 of the code, we create a variable called “numberOfRoles” and give this a 10 value.

In line 5 of the code, we pull the Array “theElements” and  variable “numberOfRoles” and use them as attributes, while naming them both as “roleThem”

In line 7 of the code, we create a function and use roleThem

In line 9 we use the while loop, which will repeat as long as the statement “numberOfRoles > 0” is true.

In line 12 we check that our variable “numberOfRoles” is always equal.

I am stuck on explaining Line 10/11 and 16-19. I know that lines 16-19 pick 10 of the elements at random and display then which you can see, however I do not know how to explain it in the correct manner. I am still learning the basics of Actionscript so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I will never understand why people take pictures of code or post the code they're talking offsite when they're asking stuff on SO. You drastically reduce the chances of people trying to help you by making them jump through more hoops. To answer your question: You already explained it. It picks a random element from a given array and return the value. [Math.floor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#floor()) is a rounding function that rounds the random value to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numberOfRolls--;
```

This subtracts 1 from the variable. It starts as 10, and runs the `while` loop as long as `numberOfRolls > 0`. As soon as it is zero, the while loop is closed.

```
var currentElement = roll(theElements);
```

This declares a variable and gives it the value that is returned by the function. In this case the function returns an Array, as is noted by line 19.

A function that looks like

```
myFunction(value:int):void{
```

accepts an integer argument and returns nothing (void)

```
myFunction(value:int):String{
```

returns a String value. But it requires a line like this

```
return "this String";
```

You can also have optional arguments. Looks like this:

```
myFunction(value:Array = null):void{
```

So the function will still run even if you don't pass an array to it.

### one more thing

> In line 5 of the code, we pull the Array “theElements” and variable “numberOfRoles” and use them as attributes, while naming them both as “roleThem”

This is not the right way to say this. We aren't naming anything here at all. `roleThem` is a *function* and we are *calling* the function (telling the play head to execute the function) and passing the function two variables: an Array called `theElements` and an integer value called `numberOfRoles`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Aura no problem. In the future, add your code to the body of the post. I've added it for you, but my edit needs to be approved by another member. Should show up soon. And please note my addition to my answer I just made (one more thing).